# Specify number of posts in PHP

Tags: php

I have a script I'm interested in, but it pulls all the data from a txt file and displays it, I really only want it to show like the last 5 post, or be able to modify the number in general.

```
<?php
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('data.txt'));
$data = array_reverse($data);
$c = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $data[$i]['date']);
$user = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($data[$i]['user']));
$message = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($data[$i]['message']));
$other = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($data[$i]['other']));
$website = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($data[$i]['website']));
$user = "$user";

if($c == 0)
{
    $c1 = '#BBBBBB';
    $c2 = '#DDDDDD';
    $c = 1;
}
else
{
    $c1 = 'CCCCCC';
    $c2 = '#EEEEEE';
    $c = 0;
}
if($data[$i]['user'] != '11jds83jd7')
{
    echo"<tr><td width=\"300\" valign=\"top\" style=\"background-color: $c1\"><strong>$user</strong><br/>$date</td><td valign=\"top\" style=\"background-color:     $c2\">$other<br>$website<br>$message<br></td></tr>";
}
}
if(count($data) == 0)
{
echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><strong>There is nothing to display.</strong><br/><br/></td></tr>';
}
$n1 = rand(0, 10);
$n2 = rand(0, 10);
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Any reason you're not using a DB? It would make it so much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit the `for` loop to specify the max, for example

```
$number = min(count($data), 5);
for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)
```

will show only 5 posts or less

Comment: Just an aside: it's better to assign `count($data)` to a variable outside the loop, otherwise it has to be recalculated for each iteration.

Comment: This worked great, thank you. I'm still trying to figure this out as I go.

Answer (score -1):

Change `for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)` to `for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)`.

Comment: The array has already been reversed, so he just needs to get the first five. Unless, he really wants the first five.

Comment: this won't work if the amount of data is lower then 5